# Arraylist check if CustomerID is in Rent ArrayList

Tags: java

I currently have 2 `Arraylist`s which have `Customer` and `Bike` constructors data. I managed to enter both successfully to rent `Arraylist` using:

```
rent.add(new Rent(customers.get(1),bike.get(1)));
```

How do I check if `CustomerID` is already in `Arraylist` rent, and it will give error saying customer already renting?

```
public Rent(Customer customer, Bike bike) {

    this.customers = customer;
    this.bike = bike;
}

public Customer(int CustID, String CustFName, String CustLName) {

    this.CustID = CustID;
    this.CustFName = CustFName;
    this.CustLName = CustLName;
}

public Bike(int BikeID, String BikeType, int PricePerDay,booleanisAvailable) {

    this.BikeID = BikeID;
    this.BikeType = BikeType;
    this.PricePerDay = PricePerDay;
    this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
}

protected ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer();
protected ArrayList<Bike> bike = new ArrayList<Bike>();
protected ArrayList<Rent> rent = new ArrayList<Rent>();
```

Comment: How do you compare two customers? Just by custId? (Note: parameters, fields, and variables in Java normally begin with lower case letters.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for a customer with a given custId, you can do this:

```
public boolean isAlreadyRenting(Customer cust) {
    return rent.stream().anyMatch(r -> r.getCustomer().getCustId() == cust.getCustId());
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @YugSingh for catching my omission!

Answer (score 0):

If you override the [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method for your objects you can use [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) on your ArrayList instances.

Comment: The goal is to find a `Rent` with a specific customer in the Rent list, not a Customer in the Customer list.

Comment: @SquatcHman it will help if you can write some code and illustrate your point.